# Name XML result column of TSQL "for xml explicit"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a query that uses `for xml explit` to return XML result.

select ...
 from ...
 order by [BatchType!1!TypeName], [FormType!2!TypeName], Tag, Parent
 for xml explicit, root('ClientImages')

But the name of resultant column name is something as cryptic as

[image]

**Is there a way to change the column name?**

---

**[ANSWER]**
I had a several nested `WITH` statements so I have saved the result of query without applying `FOR XML EXPLICIT` into a temp table `@xmlTable` and then set the XML EXPLICIT result to an XML then returned it.

```
declare @xmlResult xml
set @xmlResult =(   
    select  * 
    from    @xmlTable
    for xml explicit, root('ClientImages'))

select  @xmlResult as XmlResult
```

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?? IN 2005 and up, there's definitely no more need to "FOR XML EXPLICIT" - FOR XML PATH is much easier to use and much better

Comment: @marc_s: I have complicated structure for which I could not represent using FOR XML PATH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not, as far as I know. SQL Server Management Studio will autogenerate such a name for your XML.

You might be able to assign your output to an XML variable first and then select that to get a "nice" column name:

```
DECLARE @XmlResult XML

SELECT @XmlResult = ......
  FROM .......


SELECT @XmlResult
```

but other than that, I'm not aware of any way to influence the name of the column generated by SSMS.

Marc

Comment: Instead of restructuring `WITH` statements, I just put the result (without applying `FOR XML EXPLIT`) into a temp table and then simply returned it as XML from temp table - Answer updated.

Answer (score 17):

-- add a select ( first) and type (on the end), and as [something]

```
select
    ( 
    select 1    as tag,
    null        as parent,
    'algo'      as [nodo!1!attr]
    for xml explicit, type
    ) as [MyDesiredName]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need namespaces in your returned xml:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:http://YourNamespaceHere' as NS0)
SELECT  ( ... ) AS XmlResult
```

You can use the NS0 namespace prefix in the sub select as well.